# Compress files in a zip via PHP

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm trying to make a php file that compresses all the files in a folder on a website on CPanel. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Where am I doing wrong? Do you have any advice?

```
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath('/home/username/public_html');

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` - can you clarify further please? Does the script throw errors, does it zip some but not all files or does it do nothing? Check the PHP error log for clues... Does `$rootPath` have a value or has `realpath` failed?

Comment: I'm convinced it throws sand to neighbour's HDD ...

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` is there a section labelled zip?(Zip: enabled, Zip version etc...)

Comment: Just tested the above ( with changes to paths only ) and it ran perfectly

Comment: @BrettGregson Yes, Is enabled, zip version 1.15.4

Comment: And do you have errors turned on: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`